# Deploying Django to production correct way to do it?

Tags: django, wagtail, django-migrations

I am developing Django Wagtail application on my local machine connected to a local postgres server.

I have a test server and a production server.

However when I develop locally and try upload it there is always some issue with makemigration and migrate e.g. KeyError etc.

What are the best practices of ensuring I do not get run into these issues? What files do I need to port across?

Comment: You should not be making migrations on your servers, migrations are considered source code and should be committed to your VCS just like django does https://github.com/django/django/tree/4.0.3/django/contrib/auth/migrations

Comment: This may work for the migration files but how will I sync the database changes as well as the "migration table" entries? What have I missed ?

Comment: when you deploy your code to a new environment you should run `./manage.py migrate` to apply the database migrations, when you apply the database migrations it will automatically add them to your `django_migrations` table

Comment: I'm a bit confused the first comment says not to carry out migrations on the servers however the second comment says apply migrations on the deployment. For clarity I'm developing on a local host, what exact steps should I do to move it to the test server and the production server? Am I moving all my source code then migrating?

Comment: The first comment says NOT to `manage.py makemigrations` on your servers. The second comment says to `manage.py migrate` on your servers. They are two different actions. When I make a model change while developing, I run `manage.py makemigrations` then `git commit models.py migrations && git push`. After my model change and migrations are commited I pull them up to the server and run the migrations `git pull && ./manage.py migrate` and then restart gunicorn, or uwsgi, etc.

Comment: Just to be clear

Answer (score -2):

so ill tell you what i do and what most of the companies that i worked as a django developer did and i can tell you by experience that worked pretty well.

First containerize your application, this will make your life much more easy and you will remove external influence in your code, also will get you an easy way to reproduce your environment.

Your Dockerfile should be from some python image and should do 3 basically things:

1. Install your requirements dependencies
2. Run the `python manage.py migrate --noinput` command
3. Run a http server such as gunicorn with `gunicorn -c /gunicorn.py wsgi:application`

You ill do the makemigration in your local machine and make sure that everything is working before commit then to the repo.

In your gunicorn.py you ill put your settings to run the app such as the number of CPU, the binding port, the folder that your app is, something like:

```
import os
import multiprocessing


# Chdir to specified directory before apps loading.
# https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#chdir
chdir = '/app/'

# Bind the application on localhost both on ipv6 and ipv4 interfaces.
# https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
```

Second containerize your other stuff, for example the postgres database, the redis (for cache), a connection pooler for the database depending on the size of your application.

Its highly recommend that you have a step in the pipeline to do tests, they need to run before everything, maybe just after lint

Ok what now? now you need a way to deploy that stuff, the best for that scenario is: pull your image to github registry, and you can add a tag to that for example:

```
  IMAGE_ID=ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/$IMAGE_NAME
  # Change all uppercase to lowercase
  IMAGE_ID=$(echo $IMAGE_ID | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
  docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_ID:staging
  docker push $IMAGE_ID:staging
```

This can be add in a github action in the build step for example.

After having your new code in a new image inside github you just need to update the current one, this can be done by creaaing a script to do it in the server and running that script from github action, is something like:

```
docker pull ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/$IMAGE_NAME

echo 'Restarting Application...'
docker stop {YOUR_CONTAINER} && docker up -d 

sudo systemctl restart nginx

echo 'Cleaning old images'
sudo docker system prune -af
```

You can see that i create the image with a staging tag, you can create a rule in github actions for example to trigger that action when you create a new release for example, and create another action to be trigger in every new commit and build/deploy for a dev tag.

For the migration problem, the first thing is, when your application go live squash every migration to the first one (you can drop the database and all the migration then create the database and run the makemigration command again to reach this), so you can have a clean migration in the server. Never creates unnecessary relation between the tables, prefer always doing cached properties instead of add new columns, use UUID for unique ids, and try to not do breaking changes in the database, its hard but if you plan the database before is not so difficult to do.

Hit me if you have any questions. A lot of the stuff that i said can be done in a lot of other platforms such as gitlab, travis, circle ci, but i use the github action in the example because i think is more simple to picture.

EDIT:

I forgot to tell you to have a cron in your server doing backups of your databases, the migrate command ill apply the changes only after the verification but if something else break the database this can save your life.